# Как передать WindowScope в @Composable функцию

Tags: kotlin, compose-desktop

Как передать WindowScope  в @Composable функцию чтобы перетаскивать окно за определенный элемент.

```
@Composable
fun MainScreen( windowScope: WindowScope) {
    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
    ) {
        Column {
            windowScope.AppBar()
            Test1()
            Test2()
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun WindowScope.AppBar() {
    WindowDraggableArea {
        CurrentWeather()
    }
}
```

Comment: В `WindowScope.AppBar()`? Она же и есть функция `WindowScope`. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/extensions.html#extension-functions